# I cant display value in CGRIDVIEW with HAS_MANY relasionship (Yii)

Tags: yii, has-many

I have 2 table: 
"tblcongvanden" (ID, tencongvan) (1)-------<- (n) "tblcanbothuchien" (ID, maCongVan(FK), maCanBo, daXem)

In congvanden's model (of tblcongvanden table), i have a relation:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'canbothuchien' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'canbothuchien','maCongVan'),
        'mucdomat' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'mucdomat','maMucDoMat'),
    );
}
```

and i have a function

```
public function dsCVDchuaXem(){
    $userid = canbo::model()->find('tenDangNhap=:ten',array(':ten'=>Yii::app()->user->id))->ID;

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with= array('canbothuchien','mucdomat');
    $criteria->condition = 'maCanBo=:ma';
    $criteria->params= array(':ma'=>$userid);

    $criteria->compare('t.ID',$this->ID);
    $criteria->compare('tieuDe',$this->tieuDe,true);
    $criteria->compare('soDen',$this->soDen,true);

    $rev=$this->ngayDen;
    $rev = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{2,4})$/',"$3-$2-$1",$rev); //for day-month-year
    $criteria->compare('ngayDen', $rev,true);

    $rev=$this->ngayThang;
    $rev = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{2,4})$/',"$3-$2-$1",$rev); //for day-month-year
    $criteria->compare('ngayThang', $rev,true);

    $criteria->compare('maMucDoMat',$this->maMucDoMat);
    $criteria->together = true;

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'pagination'=> array(
            'pageSize'=> 10
        ),
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

In the index.php, how to display the field "daXem" in the Cgridview?

(I typed `'value'=>'$data->canbothuchien[0]->daXem'` and the error is "Trying to get property of non-object ", or if i typed `"value'=>'$data->canbothuchien->daXem"` it's error too)

Answer (score 3):

Not

```
'value'=>'$data->canbothuchien[0]->daXem'
```

==> :

```
'value'=>'$data->canbothuchien->daXem'
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

you can try below:

```
count($data->canbothuchien)?$data->canbothuchien[0]->daXem:""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array (
         'header'=>'daXem',
         'value'=>function($data) {
            return (!empty($data->canbothuchien->daXem)) ? $data->canbothuchien->daXem : '';
                }
    ),
```

**or**

cause the problem of **aferFind()** or **beforeFind()** hook, if have u created these hooks you may recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

'value'=>'($data->canbothuchien != null)?$data->canbothuchien->daXem:""'